# StarIO Line Mode C# SDK won't print

Tags: c#, printing

I've been working with 2 StarIO printers (TSP100 USB and LAN).
Both can be detected as online using the StarIO Line Mode C# SDK using the port name of "usbprn:Cashier" and "tcp:192.168.1.xxx".

However the Print Sample Receipt function prints nothing to printer, debugging shows no issue at all.

The same thing (detected as online, but silent on printing) happens with other SDK (iOS, Android) also.

So, is this a problem relating to the printers (given that the printers are working great with the sample printing from the application "Configuration Utility TSP100").

Any help is really appreciated!

Comment: Hard to tell when you've provided no code, no logs, just a description that it won't print. I think we're going to need more information to help you

Comment: thanks @dman2306. I've tried with the C# SDK downloaded from this link (http://www.starmicronics.com/support/zipfile.aspx?sat2=122&id=122&type=4&referrer=http://www.starmicronics.com/support/sdkdocumentation.aspx&tabText). Code is unchanged. After running the SDK application, I've entered the Port Name as "usbprn:Cashier" (already configured the printer queue name to Cashier). The application detect the Printer as online, but printing just do nothing. Thanks for the quick reply.

Comment: Chinh, I have run into the same issue that you're describing here. I was wondering if you found a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Sleette, sorry for the late response, the notification is deep down in a bunch of notification emails.

I did come-up with a temporary solution from the FAQ site, there are lot of Q&A and sample code there I could not find the original link. But there is the code that work "somehow".

It does not go through the SDK but the Window's printing queue which is of course "suck" but it works for me for now.

**Limitation**: you have to manually add LAN printer to printer queue and access it by name.

```
public class RawPrinterHelper
  {
    // Structure and API declarions:
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public class DOCINFOA
    {
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
      public string pDocName;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
      public string pOutputFile;
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]
      public string pDataType;
    }
    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "OpenPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool OpenPrinter([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string szPrinter, out IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pd);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "ClosePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool ClosePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartDocPrinterA", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool StartDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, Int32 level, [In, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] DOCINFOA di);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndDocPrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndDocPrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "StartPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool StartPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "EndPagePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool EndPagePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter);

    [DllImport("winspool.Drv", EntryPoint = "WritePrinter", SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    public static extern bool WritePrinter(IntPtr hPrinter, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount, out Int32 dwWritten);

    // SendBytesToPrinter()
    // When the function is given a printer name and an unmanaged array
    // of bytes, the function sends those bytes to the print queue.
    // Returns true on success, false on failure.
    public static bool SendBytesToPrinter(string pDocName, string szPrinterName, IntPtr pBytes, Int32 dwCount)
    {
      Int32 dwError = 0, dwWritten = 0;
      IntPtr hPrinter = new IntPtr(0);
      DOCINFOA di = new DOCINFOA();
      bool bSuccess = false; // Assume failure unless you specifically succeed.

      di.pDocName = pDocName;
      di.pDataType = "RAW";

      // Open the printer.
      if (OpenPrinter(szPrinterName.Normalize(), out hPrinter, IntPtr.Zero))
      {
        // Start a document.
        if (StartDocPrinter(hPrinter, 1, di))
        {
          // Start a page.
          if (StartPagePrinter(hPrinter))
          {
            // Write your bytes.
            bSuccess = WritePrinter(hPrinter, pBytes, dwCount, out dwWritten);
            EndPagePrinter(hPrinter);
          }
          EndDocPrinter(hPrinter);
        }
        ClosePrinter(hPrinter);
      }
      // If you did not succeed, GetLastError may give more information
      // about why not.
      if (bSuccess == false)
      {
        dwError = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
      }
      return bSuccess;
    }

    public static bool SendStringToPrinter(string pDocName, string szPrinterName, string szString)
    {
      IntPtr pBytes;
      Int32 dwCount;
      // How many characters are in the string?
      dwCount = szString.Length;
      // Assume that the printer is expecting ANSI text, and then convert
      // the string to ANSI text.
      pBytes = Marshal.StringToCoTaskMemAnsi(szString);
      // Send the converted ANSI string to the printer.
      var result = SendBytesToPrinter(pDocName, szPrinterName, pBytes, dwCount);
      Marshal.FreeCoTaskMem(pBytes);
      return result;
    }
  }
```